# Server's socket.io listener fires twice for no apparent reason

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm building an app with a chat feature using express.js, react.js and socket.io. [Here is a minimal version with the bug reproduced on Github](https://github.com/Heilemann/sockettest).

The problem is the server's `socket.on()` always fires twice, for no reason that is apparent to me.

As far as I can tell the client only ever sends a single `.emit`, but the server's `.on` always fires twice (and I'm fairly certain that event handler isn't bound twice), regardless of how many clients are connected, or indeed how I've refactored the code.

The sending client's form (input + button) appends the message to its local messages list and then dispatches `MESSAGE_NEW` to the reducer.

Here's first the `Socket.js` file.

```
import React from 'react'
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'

export const socket = socketio.connect('ws://localhost:3001')
export const SocketContext = React.createContext()
```

And here is the submit handler code from `Chat.js` (this seems to work correctly, dispatching just once):

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  if (message === '') return

  setMessages(messages => [...messages, message])
  dispatch({ type: 'MESSAGE_NEW', payload: message })
  setMessage('')
}
```

Here's `/Reducer.js`, which `.emit`'s the signal (also seems to work fine, firing just once).

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { SocketContext } from './Socket'

export default function Reducer(state, action) {
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext)

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MESSAGE_NEW':
      // this only fires once, as it should
      console.log('emitting socket')
      socket.emit('message:new', action.payload)
      break

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

But here is the relevant bit from `/server/index.js`, this is where things go wrong. No matter what I've tried, the `.on` always fires twice.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('New client connected:', socket.id)

  socket.on('message:new', message => {
    // this always fires twice, i do not understand why
    console.log('message:new: ', message, socket.id)
    socket.broadcast.emit('message:new', message)
  })
})
```

**Update:** I found out that moving the `socket.emit` from `Reducer.js` to `handleSubmit` in `Chat.js` makes it work just fine. I don't understand why since the Reducer doesn't fire twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [React documentation's on strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

Notice the last line: functions passed to `useReducer` will be invoked twice; that is why your message is being sent twice. You can confirm this by updating your reducer like so:

```js
  case "MESSAGE_NEW":
      alert("I'm running");
```

You'll notice this alert appearing twice, thanks to `React.StrictMode`.

If you remove the `<React.StrictMode>` wrapper in `src/App.js` the `test` message will no longer repeat; however, it's not fixing the underlying issue here.

The underlying issue is that you're making your reducer (which should be pure) perform an impure side-effect (in this case, sending a message via a websocket). Additionally, the reducer function also has a `useContext` call – this is also a no-op from React's perspective and is not good practice.

As you've come across in your question, Simply move the `socket.emit` into your `handleSubmit` and you should be good to go. Alternatively, you can consider a more sophisticated setup if you wish to go the reducer route; some popular configurations include Redux + Redux Thunk, or Redux + Redux Saga. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

I debugged your code and found the issue with the reducer triggering twice.

The solution is to remove the `<React.StrictMode>`
tags around your App tag in the `index.js`.

Further info on `StrictMode`: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/Heilemann/sockettest/blob/c1df22349ac1877ed625a01b14f48730b7af122d/client/src/Chat.jsx#L14-L22 you add an event listener and later try to remove it again. But since you write out the handler function

```js
message => {
  setMessages([...messages, message])
}
```

each time, the removal has no effect, since the handler to be removed is not identical to the one that you added. You must assign the handler function to a variable and use that variable in `.on` and `.off`.

Even if this does not fix the issue, it is still worth doing.

Comment: I pushed a change that does this. Unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is rendering twice, calling socket twice, giving two connection messages.

Ensure that it renders once by using your useEffect like this

In your **chat.js** import the socket.io

```
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
let socket
useEffect(() => {
    socket = socketio.connect('ws://localhost:3001')
    return () => {
      socket.off('message:new', listener)
    }
  },[])
```

In your submit handler

```
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (message === '') return
    setMessages(messages => [...messages, message])
    socket.emit('message:new', message)
    //dispatch({ type: 'MESSAGE_NEW', payload: message })
    setMessage('')
  }
```

Passing in an empty array as the second argument means the useEffect will only be called once. The bottom line is to ensure that the socket.io client is called once. props and state changes causes the component to re-render which in turns causes the socket to be connected multiple times. You can explore other patterns that cleaner. However, this is what you need to do.

Comment: I tried to create a PR for you to check the changes but the permission is denied

Comment: I'll try this out a little later today, thank you. However if the component was rendering twice, all the console.logs I have scattered throughout would fire twice as well I would think, right? But they don't?

Comment: I think I fixed the pull request issue.

But if you move the socket logic into Chat.js, Reducer won't have access to it?

Comment: If you put console.log inside your useEffect you would see that it runs twice when you send the message

Comment: Yes the Reducer wont have access to it

Comment: Yes, it runs twice but not because of the useEffect. If you read through the post you'll see that the message is sent twice from the server (and there are some details around how that happens when it's sent from the reducer, but not when it's sent from the chat). So yes it's received twice in the listener in useEffect, but because it's _sent_ twice.